# Can move multiple items simultaneously in ListBox up the list, but not down?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a strange bug that I'm having a hard time figuring out.

If I select multiple items in my ListBox and then select the up arrow, all the items move up one space perfectly as if they were one unit. However, this does not happen when clicking the down arrow to move items down one spot each in the list.

Instead, if I select an even number of items and then click the down arrow, none of the items moves at all, and if I select an odd number of items and then click the down arrow, only the bottom item moves down one space, while all the others stay where they are.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Here is the code I'm using to handle the moving of items:

```
private void MoveItemInSelectedItemsListBox(object sender)
{
  if (selectedItemsListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
  {
    // Build list of items to be moved
    List<object> listOfItemsToBeMoved = new List<object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItemsListBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
      listOfItemsToBeMoved.Add(selectedItemsListBox.SelectedItems[i]);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < listOfItemsToBeMoved.Count; k++)
    {
      var selectedItem = listOfItemsToBeMoved[k];
      int selectedItemIndex = selectedItemsListBox.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
      int numberOfItemsInList = selectedItemsListBox.Items.Count;

      // If up arrow was clicked
      if (sender.ToString().Contains("▲"))
      {
        if (selectedItemIndex == 0)
        {
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(numberOfItemsInList - 1, selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(numberOfItemsInList - 1, true);
        }
        else
        {
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(selectedItemIndex - 1, selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(selectedItemIndex - 1, true);
        }
      }
      // If down arrow was clicked
      else if (sender.ToString().Contains("▼"))
      {
        if (selectedItemIndex == numberOfItemsInList - 1)
        {
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(0, selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(0, true);
        }
        else
        {
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(selectedItemIndex + 1, selectedItem);
          selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(selectedItemIndex + 1, true);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the direction of the `for` loop: in essence, when moving items down, if you are actually moving *up* through the list while checking for items to move *down*, you end up with overlaps and other weird things. My solution was simply to do a loop going down the items if you're moving items down:

```
if (selectedItemsListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    List<object> itemsToMove = (from object item in selectedItemsListBox.SelectedItems select item).ToList();
    int numItems = selectedItemsListBox.Items.Count;

    // If up arrow was clicked
    if (sender.ToString().Contains("▲"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            var selectedItem = itemsToMove[i];
            int oldIndex = selectedItemsListBox.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
            int newIndex = oldIndex == 0 ? numItems - 1 : oldIndex - 1;

            selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
            selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selectedItem);
            selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
        }
    }
    // If down arrow was clicked
    else if (sender.ToString().Contains("▼"))
    {
        for (int i = itemsToMove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var selectedItem = itemsToMove[i];
            int oldIndex = selectedItemsListBox.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);
            int newIndex = oldIndex == numItems - 1 ? 0 : oldIndex + 1;

            selectedItemsListBox.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
            selectedItemsListBox.Items.Insert(newIndex, selectedItem);
            selectedItemsListBox.SetSelected(newIndex, true);
        }
    }
}
```

(I also took the liberty of making some of the code smaller, e.g. by changing some variable names.)

Comment: This worked very well, thank you very much. I hadn't thought about moving up and down with for loops that way. Thanks for sharing that with me!

Answer (score 1):

Found this [example](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10093833/move-items-updowm-in-listbox-control.aspx) probably a better, clearly and reusable option.

```
public class SmartListBox : ListBox
{
    //Moves the selected items up one level
    public MoveUp()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Items[i].Selected)//identify the selected item
            {
                //swap with the top item(move up)
                if (i > 0 && !Items[i - 1].Selected)
                {
                     ListItem bottom = Items[i];
                     Items.Remove(bottom);
                     Items.Insert(i - 1, bottom);
                     Items[i - 1].Selected = true;
                 }
              }
          }
     }

     //Moves the selected items one level down
     public MoveDown()
     {
         int startindex = Items.Count -1;
         for (int i = startindex; i > -1; i--)
         {
              if (Items[i].Selected)//identify the selected item
              { 
                  //swap with the lower item(move down)
                  if (i < startindex && !Items[i + 1].Selected)
                  {
                       ListItem bottom = Items[i];
                       Items.Remove(bottom);
                       Items.Insert(i + 1, bottom);
                       Items[i + 1].Selected = true;
                  }

              }
         }
     }
}
```